# Data acquisition from a Measurement Computing USB device

Tags: import, data-acquisition

I would like to use **Mathematica 9** for to acquire data from a *[Measurement Computing](http://www.mccdaq.com/)* (MC) USB-201 analog to digital (and other) device for classroom demonstration.  I do not have a budget to buy *LabView* and link Mathematica with it to accomplish what I would like to.

Within Mathematica I have tried using `Manipulate` to see if I can detect a signal (anything) from this board (excited artificially with a variable 0-5V source).  So far, I do not see any changes indicating I am communicating with this equipment.

Has anyone done something like this?  Do I need a driver, and if so, where do I get it?

Clearly, I am **not** a DAQ expert.  I need someone to speak slowly and distinctly so I can understand them.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the C++ library Measurement Computing is distributing ?

Comment: @Sektor Why the question mark... Anyway, the obvious follow-up is how? This is what the OP wants to know.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you used inside your `Manipulate`?

Comment: Have you seen the [device interface](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GamepadAndDeviceInterface.html)? And this [guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToControlObjects.html)?

Comment: @Pickett A suggestion. Well, he did not specify ...

Comment: In `Manipulate` Mathematica is able to use controllers that are visible to the system using the standard system interfaces for things like mouses, keyboards, joysticks, gamepads, etc. Your data acquisition board will typically not use this hook into the system. It needs its own drivers (which are available on the site you linked to) and it can be accessed using programs you write using the APIs available for this device. This means you have to write a program to get data into Mathematica. However, given the device's high sample rate I wonder whether you ...

Comment: ... would be able to use that in real time in Mathematica. Gamepads and the like usually have samplerates less than about 1 kHz, which is much lower than the sample rates offered by your device.

Answer (score 15):

If this device support NI-VISA (as I understood from your reference to LabVIEW), then you can use following way:

1. Install the VISA engine (available at National Instruments' web-site)
2. Use the following code.

   ```
   Needs["NETLink`"]

   lib = LoadCOMTypeLibrary[
   "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IVI \Foundation\\VISA\\VisaCom\\GlobMgr.dll"]
   mgr = NETNew["Ivi.Visa.Interop.ResourceManagerClass"];
   OSA = NETNew["Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488Class"];

   devs = mgr@FindRsrc["?*instr"];
   devdescr = {};
   Do[
   OSA@IO = mgr@Open[devs[[i]]];
   OSA@WriteString ["*IDN?"];
   id = OSA@ReadList[];
   AppendTo[devdescr, id[[2]]],
   {i, 1, Length[devs]}];

   If[devs == $Failed, devs = {"empty"}; devdescr = {"NoDeviceDetected"}];
   ```

The first string enables [NETLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/ref/NETLink.html) and the next three strings load the VISA global manager and create an object named OSA.

The next block asks the VISA global manager for connected devices and gives you a list, **devs**, with their inner descriptions, **devdescr**.

You can connect to the needed device using the command:

```
OSA@IO = mgr@Open[devs[[x]]]
```

Where x is number in the list...
After this, you can send any commands to a device using

```
OSA@WriteString ["<command>"]
```

And read answers using:

```
OSA@ReadList[]
```

Or

```
OSA@ReadString[]
```

The list of supported commands should be in the user manual for your device.

Comment: Shouldn't "\\IVI \Foundation\\" be "\\IVI\\Foundation\\"?

Comment: In "Needs["NETLink\`"]", what does the ` do (after the "k")?

Comment: @Peter, the backtick denotes the context of the functions about to be loaded by `Needs[]`; in this case, ``NETLink` ``.

Comment: In the line "devs = mgr@FindRsrc["?*instr"];" I get this error: "A .NET exception occurred: \
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8002000B): HRESULT = \ 8002000b   at Ivi.Visa.Interop.ResourceManagerClass.FindRsrc(String expr).". What may be wrong?

Comment: @LeoRon7, Did you check the **mgr** value? Try `NETTypeInfo[mgr]`, do it has such method as FindRsrc? If it has then try `mgr@FindRsrc["?*"]` 
Will it show you any connected instruments?

Comment: Yes. I found the method FindRsrc in mgr and tried all possible strings for "?*". I can execute some functions of mgr such as mgr@componentversion, mgr@description, mgr@progID and they return the correct value. But mgr@FindRsrc["?*instr"] returns the same error. Any other hint?

Comment: @LeoRon7, Which type of device connection do you use (USB, GP-IB, LAN,..)?
 I've one recommendation for you regarding to device detection. You can download and install the official client from KeySight for example (IO suite) or from your device vendor and try to detect the device through it. If it is successful then you can try again with your program using device identifier obtained from that client. So you can omit the step with `FindRsrc` and go directly to `mgr@Open["that identifier"]` 
May be your VISA version is wrong or something else..

Comment: The new version of NI-VISA has another architecture of software and don't have the globmgr.dll Therefore, the old version is needed to use the presented approach. Or you can find the new way..

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, it works fine.

But the following string had to be corrected in my case:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI \Foundation\VISA\VisaCom\GlobMgr.dll"]
by:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\VisaCom\GlobMgr.dll"]

And I did not receive a device number, so I guessed 1 and that was the right number.[[image: listing in my case]

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81372)

Comment: @m_goldberg Isn't this more than a "thank you?"  It seems to contain additional information required to solve the problem on this user's system