# Communicating with USB device

Tags: input-devices

I would like to control and acquire data from a USB device using MMA 13 running on Windows 10. (The device is an Ocean Optics HR2000 spectrometer.) I Do not have a device driver or an API for the device. I do have a manual listing commands which are sent to the device as byte sequences, and the format of data which is also read back in bytes. I am not familiar with USB communications.

Does anyone know of a general method by which Mathematica can identify the device and communicate with it?

Comment: see [How do you read/write a usb device with mathematica](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/253531) and [Communicating with an Arduino Uno over a serial connection](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/158717?p_p_auth=FZgcI0JJ) and [data-acquisition-from-a-measurement-computing-usb-device](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40695/data-acquisition-from-a-measurement-computing-usb-device)

Comment: Thanks, @Nasser. I may have found an NI-VISA driver as discussed in one of the references. I’ll try it!